# Check variable values in TLA+

Tags: tla+

I have to check the variable values by using TLA+ in TLC. For example

Res_Word == {"_","N"}

variables my_variable = "Some_valueONE"

Check == my_variable \in Res_Word

* means check it if variable contains some of the specific value as required in set.

Answer (score 0):

what is your specific problem with the provided approach? Here's a PlusCal example.

```
---- MODULE test ----
EXTENDS Integers, Sequences, TLC, FiniteSets
(* --algorithm test
variables res_positive_match = "N", res_negative_match = "Y";
define
    Res_Word == {"_","N","M"}
    NotInResWord == res_negative_match \in Res_Word
end define;

begin P:
  print <<"res_positive_match:", res_positive_match \in Res_Word>>;
  print <<"res_negative_match:", res_negative_match \in Res_Word, "NotInResWord:", NotInResWord>>;
  print <<"sets matching:", {"N","_"} \subseteq Res_Word>>;
end algorithm; *)
\* BEGIN TRANSLATION
\* END TRANSLATION
=====
```

Which outputs something like:

```
<<"res_positive_match:", TRUE>>
<<"res_negative_match:", FALSE, "NotInResWord:", FALSE>>
<<"sets matching:", TRUE>>
```